# IKEA Tradfri bulbs showing up as "other" in the Alexa App, instead of "light."

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo, ikea-tradfri

I have my IKEA Tradfri bulbs connected through the Tradfri Gateway.  They are all showing version 1.2.214, which the app says is the latest version, as well as the gateway which is 1.3.14.

Inside the Alexa app, I've installed the bulbs and they show up and work perfectly (outside of routines), but the **Type** listed under device settings is *other*.  If they were showing up as *light* instead of *other*, I would be able to just say, "Alexa, lights on." vs "Alexa, turn on Bedroom/Living Room" as they would be associated with the Echo Dot in each room's group.

Has anyone figured out a way to change the **Type** from *other* to *light*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not change the type from the app side, it needs updating from the Alexa skill.

So you will need to wait for IKEA to update the cloud side of their app to include device types.